# Is a closed universe symmetric?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, symmetry, universe, space-expansion

Say our universe is closed, at some point in the future it will reach a maximum and then begin to contract, will it return to say the point we are now in exactly the reverse manner? For example, as the universe expands it cools, presumably as it contracts it heats up; when the scale factor of the universe returns to the size it is now, would the temperature return to 2.7 K?

Comment: You're mixing up two different issues. One is the question of whether our universe's spatial topology is closed. The other is whether our universe will eventually recollapse. Older books may treat these as equivalent questions, but they are not equivalent when dark energy exists. We know for sure that our universe will not eventually recollapse, but we don't know whether it's closed. So this question may be of academic or philosophical interest, but it isn't relevant to our own universe.

Comment: @BenCrowell you seem to have missed the point of my question, ignore the topology of the universe, it isn't relevant why it collapses, it just does. My question is with regards to modelling such a universe. For example, in an expanding universe the temperature of the CMB goes as 1/scale factor, is this true of the reverse (a contracting universe)?  Whilst i agree that it seems that our universe will not re-collapse at the moment  the nature of the field means that this isn't guaranteed. Furthermore, i never suggested our universe would collapse  but it is relevant to  understanding cosmology.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, there is no time reversal symmetry in cosmological expansion-contraction. Entropy of the universe would continue to increase even when expansion changes to contraction. Fusion in stars would continue to produce heavier elements, accreting black holes would continue growing, etc.

However, for some subsystems that could as a first approximation be considered [isentropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process) there could be approximate symmetry. For example cosmic microwave background radiation (CMB) which mostly could be considered decoupled from the rest of the matter could be considered such subsystem. And so, when after expansion the scale factor returns to its present value the temperature of CMB would also return to its present value. However, this is only first approximation. In the next approximation, the CMB at present possesses measurable anisotropy, it also does interact with other matter, and so after expansion and contraction the deviations of the CMB from isotropy and thermal spectrum would only grow even during contraction phase.